# Why Spring authorization server accepts null and "" as valid scopes while generating token?

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I have observed that spring authorization server accepts null and empty string as valid scopes and processes validations in OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuthenticationToken class. Is this valid?
Also, token generation happens by default with no scopes passed in request. Is this also valid?

Thanks

Comment: valid in accordance to what spec? Scope is not a mandatory claim, in fact no claim is mandatory, they are all optional in oauth2. Using JWT is optional in fact. So you need to be more specific. Valid, in accordance to what?

Comment: Valid in accordance to token generation

Comment: I just wrote, scope claim is optional